# Android Navigation component deeplink backstack

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-components

I am doing [navigation component codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-navigation/index.html#0).
In 10 part we add deeplink widget.

I replace destination to R.id.flow_step_two_dest

```
  val custAtgs = FlowStepFragmentArgs(2)
    val pendingIntent = NavDeepLinkBuilder(context)
        .setGraph(R.navigation.mobile_navigation)
        .setDestination(R.id.flow_step_two_dest)
        .setArguments(custAtgs.toBundle())
        .createPendingIntent()
```

And have this graph

[image]

It works. After press back it is returned to home, but I expect that it will return to Step One.

Is it right behavior? Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

It is the intended behavior.

This is from [step 10](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-navigation/index.html#9) :

> The backstack is generated using the destinations specified with
>   app:startDestination. In this app we only have one activity and one
>   level of navigation, so the backstack will take you to the home_dest
>   destination.

Pressing the back button should take you back to `home_dest`.

> More complicated navigation can include nested navigation graphs. The
>   app:startDestination at each level of the nested graphs determines the
>   backstack.

Wrap `flow_step_one_dest` and `flow_step_two_dest` into a nested graph and set `flow_step_one_dest` as the start destination.

Pressing the back button should take you back to `flow_step_one_dest` then `home_dest`.